# How to change the date format in Oracle BI Publisher?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, business-intelligence, obiee, bi-publisher

How do I change the format of the date while creating a report using data model which I created using a simple SQL query which fetches aggregated data from a data warehouse? I need the date in a simple dd-mon-yy format. I am not able to locate where the format option exists in BI Publisher. The BI Component I am using is PivotTable.

[image]

The problem with order:

Although, I have ordered my data in the data model, still the data is not showing up in the proper order in the chart. The same thing is working fine on the data table. See below -

[image]

Comment: At your query level, `to_date` and `to_char` are your friends. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need the date in a simple dd-mon-yy format.

Did you use the proper format model in your query?

For example,

If the date value in the database is `20150225`, then you need to first convert it to date using **TO_DATE** and respective **FORMAT MODEL**.

`to_date('20150225','YYYYMMDD')`

In order to display the date in your desired format, just use **TO_CHAR** and desired format model:

`to_char(to_date('20150225','YYYYMMDD'),'DD-MON-YYYY')`

Have a look at this [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlpublisher/entry/how_to_keep_your_dates_from_go).

**Update** Regarding alphabetical sorting on month in chart

Found the following information on [web](http://www.postseek.com/meta/1fdca1b3baf186732940f59a808744c0):

If you are designing chart using **RTF template**, please try this:

1. Right click chart image - click size - click AltText tab
2. Copy the chart code into a notepad
3. Look for the tag ColLabelsIt will be something like this:

> ColLabelsxsl:for-each select=".//G_1"
>   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"xsl:sort
>   order="ascending" select="FIRST_NAME"/Labelxsl:value-of
>   select="FIRST_NAME" //Label/xsl:for-each/ColLabels

Please see the sorting order that has been highlighted. In sorting order, you can add the field/column that is holding the month/year combination. If your chart is using group function then `xsl:sort order="ascending" select="current-group()/FIRST_NAME"/`

Comment: The solution does work but going on the same lines, I converted the month into 'Mon-Yy' and created a chart - now the months are out of order - they are in alphabetical order!

Comment: Use to_char only in select, while you order, just order by the original date column. For example, `SELECT to_char(hiredate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM emp
ORDER BY hiredate;
`

Comment: Thanks, I am aware about how we do it generally. So, essentially the publisher will take the data in the same order as in the data model. We cannot change the order on the front end. Is that right?

Comment: The tool will take the same format as that of your locale specific NLS_DATE_FORMAT

Comment: Although, the data table is showing me the same order as prescribed in the data model that I'm using, the chart is still showing the months basis alphabetical order.

Comment: No, that was earlier. I've already changed the settings to Dd-Mon-RR now. Also, now that I don't have a date column, it should not matter. The date is in 'Dd-Mon-Yy' and the month is in 'Mon-Yy' - both explicitly converted into char using to_char

Comment: I used the basic template provided by OBIEE. The format is .xpt

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the column ( type : date)
2. Click on properties (left Bar)
3. Change: formating Style (Oracle) and formating Mask ( DD/MM/YYYYY)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.
Follow the navigation.

Double click the field-> Select Type as Date and Date Format as dd-MMM-yyyy.
This should resolve your issue

I wanted to post a image, but no reputation.

How this helps..

Answer (score 0):

excel stores dates as a number calculated as number of days from jan 00 1900.  So you can use pl/sql to calculate the that number, pass it on back to the template as a number and let excel do its thing, render it as a date.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).